# eclipse C project shows errors (Symbol could not be resolved) but it compiles

Tags: c, eclipse, indexing

I have got access to a C project at work that I have to implement some stuff in. I was able to load it into eclipse and can `Project -> Build All` it. Compilation shows no errors or warnings. But in eclipse, there are a lot of errors shown. One example:

---

There is an enum

```
typedef enum MeasurementType {
    PN, BB, AM, RES
} MEAS_TYPE;
MEAS_TYPE type;
```

in one of the files. It is used somewhere else and produces an error like this:
[image]

It is most interesting, that only `AM` seems to be a problem, not `PN` or `BB`.

---

I haven't found a satisfying solution to this. I already tried to include all possible directories I could think of in `Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols` (like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10554556/1137043) suggests), but that didn't help.

The project itself is compiled with Makefiles (which is why I need `Project -> Build All`). Can it be that eclipse does not interpret those Makefiles correctly or something? I am a bit lost after messing around with that stuff for a few hours and not getting a single step forward.

EDIT: Here are some screenshots for my build-relevant project properties (at least I believe they are relevent :D). Tell me if you need more information.

[image] [image]

Comment: You might like to let Eclipse rebuild its index.

Comment: @alk Already did that (was the last point in the suggestion of the SO answer I linked). Didn't help...

Comment: What kind of Eclipse project is this? Did you provide the makefile? It looks as if Eclipse (**not** gcc) is setup to parse the wrong or some additonally, propably outdated includes.

Comment: @alk I added some screenshots. The Makefile is in the root directory of the project. It is a normal C/C++ project (or do you mean something else with that question?).

Comment: @alk Hm, you mean in `Project Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes`?

Comment: Most propably yes at least if `MeasurementType` comes from your sources. Or is it declared by any library having it's headers installed under `/usr/incldue' or any other system include path?

Comment: @alk I just found out that when I click on `AM` and switch to the declaration (`F3`), I get to choose between the correct one and a variable that is defined somewhere else. I just renamed the enum constant and there we go. All the other errors were solvable by the same procedure. I guess I am not used to this non-OOP stuff... ;) If you put your suggestions in an answer, I can accept and upvote it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if Eclipse (not gcc) is setup to parse the wrong or some additonally, propably outdated (include) source files.

Comment: My last comment to the question says how this answer solved my problem. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @moooeeeep thought about that but I wanted to award alk for his quick and helpful help.

Answer (score 2):

Since I got a suggestion from moooeeeep, I will post the solution here. I am still accepting alk's answer, because he was the one that showed me towards the right direction.

**My solution:**

If I click on `AM` in eclipse (the one that is underlined with red) and press `F3` to go to the declaration, it actually asked me to which declaration I want to go. It listed the (correct) enum constant as well as some variable from somewhere else. Therefore the problem was that multiple declarations of `AM` were present in different code locations.

I fixed this problem by just **renaming** the `enum` constant to something else (`AN` in my case). There is no variable with the same name in the code and therefore eclipse was able to refactor it correctly.

Comment: Helped to me as well. I didn't notice I redefined the enum values!

Comment: In my case, there's just one declaration and F3 takes me right to it. However, the indexer still says it is not resolved, oddly.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite an old question, but I hope this short answer can be useful to someone.

I was having similar errors with enums in the IDE but not when compiling, which seemed to indicate a bug in Eclipse's Codan. After upgrading to the new version of Eclipse (Neon 4.6) released in June, the errors have disappeared. Just try updating Eclipse!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up switching to a different IDE for that project. But I will try with Eclipse Neon again. I would much rather work with Eclipse. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug report added in Eclipse CDT Bugzilla with regard to this problem: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=439553

Comment: Thank you, that is good to know. Hopefully it gets fixed as this is quite annoying. ;)

Comment: Over 8 years now and the bug is still going strong. :)