# Cannot use mysql functions in Eclipse CDT Juno

Tags: mysql, c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm getting an error on my source file for the mysql functions Im using. I setup my inclusion path and the libraries. The error is, for example: `undefined reference to _mysql_init` when I call `mysql_init`. Whats interesting is, I can click on the function and it will go directly to the `mysql.h` function declaration

Comment: So, does your project build without errors? Or does the compiler or linker proclaim the missing of `msql_init()` during the build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your project builds well: You might like to let Eclipse rebuild its symbol index.

To do so: Right-click the project and select `Index->Rebuild`

(see also: [eclipse C project shows errors (Symbol could not be resolved) but it compiles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13269092/694576))