# Type 'uint32_t' could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11, gcc, eclipse-cdt

I am working on a C++ program in Eclipse (3.8.1) CDT. I am using the gcc compiler on Debian 8. I'm also using an open source library called opendnp3 written in C++, which requires **uint32_t** to resolve as it's a parameter in several method calls and constructors.

In the opendnp objects, intellisense doesnt list

`__uint32_t` however, DOES resolve.

The type is defined in `<cstdint>` (`<cstdint>` resolves just fine). I can open the declaration and clearly see '`using ::uint32_t;`' in there.

In my searching, I've added `-std=c++11` to 'All options' under 'C/C++ Build --> Settings -> Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler' and I've also rebuilt the project index and restarted Eclipse, but it still doesn't resolve.

Here's the code so far: **Edited to a simple HelloWorld project to help diagnose problem**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint> //has uint32_t defined
using namespace std;

int main() {
    __uint32_t t = 0;  //resolves just fine
    uint32_t i = 0; //Type could not be resolved
    auto x = "123"; //C++ 11 working
    cout << "Foo!" << endl; // prints Foo!
    return 0;
}
```

CDT Console after a build attempt:

23:10:52 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project FOO ****
make all 
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

23:10:52 Build Finished (took 133ms)

Comment: "I am using the gcc compiler on Debian 8." What gcc version is that? You can check with `gcc -v`.

Comment: Is this causing a compilation error or just the Eclipse UI is marking an error?

Comment: Try `std::uint32_t`. There are probably more than one `xxx::uint32_t` in that barrage of `using namespace yyy;`, which makes the name ambiguous.

Comment: gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)

Comment: when i try std::uint32_t is still unresolved. The intellisense doesn't show any 'uint' types.

Comment: It causes a compilation error, not just Eclipse UI error.

Comment: Try to move #include <cstdint> //uint32_t

to the first line. How opendnp3 refers to uint32_t ?

Comment: Time to cut down the problem. if `#include <iostream> #include <cstdint> int main() { uint32_t test  =0; std::cout << test << std::endl; }` doesn't reproduce the problem, then @BaummitAugen is probably right.

Comment: I actually just tried to create a new Project without all of the other references, and I still see the same error.

Comment: Also please specify exact compiler error, does it complain on the first line in your main() ? 

To check that c++ eleven is enabled just add something like: auto x = "123"; it's c++11 feature

Comment: @ErikJL even this doesn't compiles?
#include <iostream>


int main() {
   uint32_t x = 0;
   cout << x << endl;
   return 0;
}

Comment: Yeah, even a fresh HelloWorld project that i only modified by declaring a uint32_t wont' compile. Also, the 'auto x = "123"; ' works just fine.

Comment: Weird. is `__uint32_t_defined` defined? At this point I don't expect it will be.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 uint32_t i = 0;
 auto x = "123";
 cout << "Foo!" << endl; // prints Foo!
 return 0;
}

Comment: @user4581301 - __uint32_t DOES resolve.

Comment: Recommend editing question to include the test code from two comments up. It's more direct and MCVE-y than the code sample you have now.

Comment: Let's see if this is an Eclipse config problem. If you build the Foo test code from the command line what happens? `g++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp`

Comment: Good point - just edited it.

Comment: g++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp creats a binary file 'a.out' but no executable file.

Comment: a.out should be the executable, but it did compile without warnings or errors, yes?

Comment: Oh ok yea ./a.out does indeed execute (sorry, I'm very new to both C++ and eclipse).  So I have an Eclipse issue then yeah?

Comment: Why do you always include `using namespace std;`.  Is it the case that `std::uint32_t` works?  If not, the `using namespace` is noise (and generally a bad idea).  If so, that needs to be stressed. Also, edit the `-v` results into the question itself.

Comment: Wait a second, what evidence do you have that there is a build problem here?  ... a squiggle or intellisense only?

Comment: Recommend copying Eclipse's output in the CDT Build Console (Console tab down at the bottom) and adding it to your question. This will allow us to see both the compiler command line and the error message verbatim. On the dangers of `using namespace std;`, give this a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @Yakk - std::uint32_t does not resolve in Eclipse, but main.cpp does compile with command line g++. As far as #include std, well, I'm not sure... 95% of my programming is in C# so I'e always used includes instead of fully qualifying types. I did not realize that was bad practice, so thanks for the heads up.  Apologize for the ignorance, but what are you referring to when you mention the "-v" results?

Comment: @erik important information from comment discussions should be put in OP, as comments are deleted often.

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is old, but I feel it's worth mentioning that I was having this exact problem and was able to resolve it just be rebuilding the index: right-click the project, "Index", "Rebuild". You said that you had rebuilt the index and it didn't help; importantly, I did this after adding `-std=c++11` to the command line for the compiler specified in the "CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings", which can be found by opening project properties and going to "C/C++ General", "Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc", "Providers" tab. You wouldn't, if I understand correctly, need to do this with GCC version 6+ as it defaults to C++14; I'm using GCC 5.4 myself.

If that doesn't help, the best path for debugging the issue is probably to open the declaration for `cstdint` (the include file itself - so, right click `cstdint` within the `#include` directive, and choose "open declaration") - this will show you the included file, with sections greyed out if they are precluded via preprocessor macros (`#ifdef` and the like). You may be able to see immediately why `uint32_t` is not considered defined. In my case, the `__cplusplus` macro had an unsuitable value and this led me to adding `-std=c++11` to the compiler command line as mentioned above - *but* I still needed to rebuild the index before the problem was fully resolved.

Answer (score 4):

Try to enable the *CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings* in Project>Properties>Preprocessor Includes>Providers.

Comment: Looks like its already there. Under GNU C++, I see 4 entries, one of which is CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings [Shared]

Comment: Fixed my issue. Thanks!

Comment: Eclipse 2023-09 does not have this menu: Project>Properties>Preprocessor Includes

Answer (score 0):

After adding `-std=c++11`, do this:

> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Symbols -> GNU C++

Click `Add` on the left side and paste `__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` (ensure to append and prepend two underscores) into `Name` and leave `Value` blank.