# cv::utils::fs has not been declared on Eclipse 4.14

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV 4.2.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.
This code here

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>

#include <iostream>

#define DIR "../data/checkerboard_images"
#define PATTERN "*_color.png"

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    //load filenames
    std::vector<cv::String> v;

    cv::utils::fs::glob(DIR, PATTERN, v);

    return 0;
}
```

gives me the following

```
error: ‘cv::utils::fs’ has not been declared
```

I think I have to include some files, but I can't figure out the right one, please help.

EDIT:
I have to include (thank you @spinkoo)

```
#include <opencv2/core/utils/filesystem.hpp>
```

and to get rid of CODAN errors on Eclipse editor I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522048/eclipse-compiles-but-codan-internal-code-analyzer-gives-errors-for-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the following include

```
#include <opencv2/core/utils/filesystem.hpp>
```