# Eclipse Error Highlighting with Auto C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, ide, syntax-highlighting, auto

I am having issues with eclipse c++ syntax highlighting
I am using Eclipse-cpp version 4.7.3-1, installed from here: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?name=eclipse-cpp

I have the following code:

```
for (auto& i : entityFactories) {
        if (i->getFactoryName() == type) {
            worldEntities.push_back(i->loadEntity(d, *this));
        }

    }
```

When this code is in eclipse, it is highlighted and marked as "Method could not be resolved". However, the code still built successfully without error.

When I changed the code to

```
for (EntityFactory* i : entityFactories) {
        if (i->getFactoryName() == type) {
            worldEntities.push_back(i->loadEntity(d, *this));
        }

    }
```

The issue was resolved. Is this an issue with the auto keyword in Eclipse? Or is there some setting I can change so I can use the auto keyword without any problems? I tried this post here: [Eclipse C/C++ Shows Errors but Compiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554266/eclipse-c-c-shows-errors-but-compiles) but this did not fix my issue.

Comment: What version of Eclipse and CDT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to config Eclipse to use C++0x or newer. Check out this article: [Guide to Eclipse with C++11 standard](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/282618/787571/).

Comment: This doesn't seem to be necessary in recent versions of Eclipse and CDT.

Comment: But we don't know which Eclipse version does OP use.

Comment: A problem, isn't it? Part of why I asked the asker to provide the versions quite a while ago. Odds are pretty good that you'll turn out to be right, but it's still a roll of the dice.