Errors displayed in Espressif-IDE when including standard C++ libraries
In our ESP32-C3 project we have a mix of C and C++ code. Naturally we would like to use standard C++ libraries, like <string>, <vector> etc.
Adding these with #include immediately marks it as an error. Same goes for c* libraries like <cstring>, statements "using namespace std;" and other. Basic operators like calling a method from an object e.g. myobj.dosomething(); are marked as errors too, because IDE considers myobj an integer due to std::vector used as class member. Furthermore, all .cpp files that include the one with an error are also marked, creating a chain reaction that paints pretty much entire project in red.
The code itself compiles and runs OK, so ESP-IDF is fine. It is only an editor in IDE or whatever code analyzer is running in it gives us headache and slows down development a lot. It is very weird, since it recognizes the rest of C++ code just fine and supports helpful features like ctrl-click jump to the class sources.
Is there any way to make IDE recognize standard C++ libraries?
Eclipse plugin version 3.0, IDF version 5.3
UPDATE
I hate for a bounty to be wasted, so at this point I'll accept any answer explaining who and how exactly does the syntax highlighting in the Eclipse editor. Is it some generic C++ parser or editor itself (LSP editor?) or the ESP-IDF framework? The latter makes most sense, but I doubt it is the case here.

Not sure you ever read the documentation and done the proper configuration/setup for c++ support yet.

@hcheung That is a nice assumption which is unfortunately not the case. We've read everything we could find on the C++ compatibility, beginning with the documentation at that link. It has exactly zero references to "configuration/setup", instead focusing on proper coding for ESP-IDF. As I mentioned in the question, we have ho problems with IDF, the program compiles and runs just fine. An it is rather big program, sharing dozens of proprietary C++ libraries with STM32 code. So, if you have any specific IDE configuration that we could have missed, please, point it out.


"Adding these with #include immediately marks it as an error." =>
What is the error exactly complaining about? 2. "are marked as errors too" => is that the same error or a different one? In general, I'd suggest trying to create a new project in that your same IDE/environment setup and try first a C++-only stuff, then C-only, and then combine them, to see if the error is reproduced from scratch, in order to understand where exactly is the problem between your IDE-plugin parts. Consider posting a question in their lib here https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues if I got it right.


@Hack06 when I hover the mouse over include line pop-up says "'queue' file not found". In the sources that include the one with error it says "in included file: 'queue' file not found". We created a project from scratch, and both C and our own C++ code worked fine with zero warnings or errors. That is, until we included first standard C++ library. It was  I think, and it was painted red right away. I did post the same question to espressif forum. Did not think about github though.

What is your C++ std version? C++11/14/17/20/23?

@Maple I suppose that your IDE has some issues with paths to resolve your std includes. So you may need to understand how it's working. Try Project --> Properties --> C/C++ General --> Paths and Symbols or around there. It's really hard or maybe even impossible to give you hints on such issue without having actually access to your development environment. I doubt anyone can give you a reasonable answer here, unless run into the same troubles with the same setup that you got.

@Red.Wave by default ESP-IDF uses C++23. We did not see any reasons to change this. Having said that, our own libraries are shared with STM32 projects that use C++11, so all shared code is written to compile on that.

@Hack06 there is no "path & symbols" in Espressif-IDE. I guess that menu comes from installed modules specific for the platform (e.g. STM32CubeIDE has it). All our developers installed Espressif following installation instructions to the letter, and all are having the same issue. I also found a few years old question on espressif forum describing this problem (i.e. code compiles and runs OK, but editor shows errors). There is not a single answer or comment on that one.

Looks like you're using CDT editor which cannot keep up with C++17. LSP may remove the error marks, but it seems to be underdeveloped and troublesome too. You may try to find a different IDE with costumizable toolchain parameters; so you can use a cross compiler for STM32. I don't know if Vscode is capable of that or not; you gotta do some research.

I just found this old link with a similar issue which may effectively be the reason of your environment as well. Hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554266/eclipse-c-c-shows-errors-but-compiles/61087623

@Hack06 All the answers there revolve around adding framework paths to "Paths & Symbols" Eclipse menu, which is missing in Espressif-IDE. It is indeed interesting that Arduino team did not manage to setup their environment out of the box to solve this problem. At least they did not hide "Path & Symbols", giving the users an option to fix it.

I like hunting for bounties, and as you've modified your OP to find a workaround for your issue, here's my answer.
So I created a brand new C++ project in my Eclipse, and in a wizard-created project introduced a real error in imports on its 2nd line in the below screenshot. Then, from the menu item Window->Preferences I've changed the way Eclipse is highlighting the errors in its editor. The level of control is more than abundant IMO and should serve you as a workaround to disable highlighting errors in your IDE while it's compiling fine. But beware that it will apply to real errors as well.
My guess is that in your Eclipse environment you may have some more items under those "Annotation types" that may be populated by your plug-ins, so perhaps you should located them and remove their highlighting only, instead of the "Errors" in my screenshot below.


I think you've misunderstood the updated question. I've asked who does syntax highlighting in editor in order to narrow down the problematic Eclipse component or configuration ("Is it some generic C++ parser or editor itself or the ESP-IDF framework?"). Making errors invisible will not solve other problems, like parser treating C++ object as "int" only because the class has  member.

Ok, in my opinion it's just Eclipse-IDE which has that built-in highlighting for its editor, with or without any plugin that may override that functionality. But I let others to give a better answer.
